# Permitir download dentro de Iframe no Android

Tags: android, ionic3

Estou desenvolvendo um app com ionic que tem uma página webview dentro de um iframe, nessa webview existe um botão de download que funciona normalmente no browser, mas no android não funciona. Creio que o Android esteja bloqueando esse download, gostaria de saber como habilitar para que o download seja feito diretamente, como faz no browser.